# How to remove the arrows when placing the "Tab" button and dashes when I press the space bar that appear in my Sql Server environment?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following problem, maybe it's quite simple but I could not find the solution.

It happens that without realizing I did a combination of keys (ShortCuts) and the code editor changed, now when I write any query I get something similar to scripts
in the spaces I have (when I press the space bar) and arrows when I press the "Tab" button

Does anyone know where this is configured? Thank you ... SQL SERVER

Here is an example

```
SELECT-*-FROM-MI_TABLA  
WHERE--COLUMNA-=-'ABCDE'
```

Comment: Is this in ssms? Do you use any sort of add on like SQL Prompt or SQL Complete?

Comment: In SSMS, Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard. See if something in there is custom to what you are seeing and remove that shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

In SSMS menu bar try **Edit > Advanced > View White Space** . This should remove arrows.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know that. Thanks!